# "Eч!", "Ач!' та інші "Ой!". Коли доречно який вигук вживати?

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, стилістика

[Тут](https://ukurainajin.dreamwidth.org/67814.html) цікаву абетку побачив.

> Абетка, Барва, Веселка, Горобець, Ґава, Дзиґа, Еч! Єдність, Жовтень,
>   Звитяга, Ирій, Істота, Їжачок, Йой! Комаха, Латаття, Мереживо,
>   Незалежність, Обрій, Праска, Равлик, Смерека, Тин, Уряд, Філіжанка,
>   Хвиля, Цуцик, Черешня, Школяр, Щогла, українсЬка, Юнак, Ялівець.

[Знайшов](http://sum.in.ua/s/ech) `Еч!` у словнику.

> ЕЧ, виг., розм., рідко. Те саме, що ач. Еч, яка цокотуха! (Данило
>   Мордовець, I, 1958, 505)

Але зараз я не розумію, коли треба вживати [Еч!](http://sum.in.ua/s/ech), а - коли [Ач!](http://sum.in.ua/s/ach) чи інші [Ой!](http://sum.in.ua/s/Oj).

Comment: Поставив тег «стилістика», бо вважаю, що вигуки здебільшого не є нормованою частиною літературної мови.

Answer (score 1):

Вигуки можна вживати в численних емоційно наповнених ситуаціях, згідно з наведеними вами тлумаченнями з [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/oj).

Однак, як зазначено в [дослідженні з семантики цієї частини мови](http://philology.knu.ua/files/library/ukrmov/2012/26-40.pdf),

> Вигук як мовне явище є одним із перших філогенетичних феноменів
>   системи мови. Однак, незважаючи на численні дослідження, він все ще
>   **не знайшов** єдиного розуміння своєї сутності, частиномовної
>   належності, **семантичної визначеності**.

Почувати розгубленість щодо "доречності у вживанні" можна лише всередині першого пункту класифікації звуконаслідувальних (на відміну від похідних від повнозначних частин мови типу "Боже", "Спасибі", "Так" і т.п.) вигуків Л.Мацько:

а) багатозначні, з широким емоційним діапазоном: а!, о!, е!, ай!, ой!, ох! та їх фонетичні варіанти а-а-а!, о-о!, е-е-е!; 
б) порівняно однозначні, із семантикою негативності типу пхе!, пхи!, пхі!, пху!, тьху!, фе!, фі!, фу!, хе!, хі!, 
в)вигуки з вужчим і одноманітнішим значенням (і!, у!, ух!, ба!, леле!, ого!) 
(Мацько Л. І. Семантика вигуків та звуконаслідувань
// Українська мова і література в школі. – 1985. – № 2. – С. 56–62. ).

Щодо багатозначних вигуків, семантиці кожного з них має бути присвячено окреме дослідження, яке, втім, не може претендувати на вичерпаність. Як приклад, у цитованому достідженні щодо вигука *А* було проаналізовано лише 446 випадків вживання вигука *А*, з яких 288 ілюструють вісім семантичних варіантів (‘здогад’ (74), ‘привітне впізнавання’ (44), ‘байдужість’ (41), ‘досада’ (30), ‘відчай’ (29), ‘пригадування’ (25), ‘зрозуміло’ (23) і ‘злорадство’ (22)). Багатозначність, пластичність семантики цього вигука дозволяють вживати його і в інших випадках, надаючи власного, лише в певній ситуації зрозумілого, значення.

В [іншому дослідженні](http://file:///C:/Users/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0/Downloads/Nchnpu_10_2014_11_33%20(1).pdf) окреслено причини складнощів у визначенні семантики вигуків:

> Щодо семантики вигуків, то вона має «конкретно-ситуативний характер і
>   розкривається у контексті, у зв’язках із іншими словами, за допомогою
>   інтонації, може доповнюватися мімікою, жестами»  Інтонація відіграє
>   важливу роль в оформленні речення з вигуковим елементом: «усі вигуки
>   супроводжує специфічне інтонаційне оформлення – інтонація видільності,
>   проте не завжди оклична, бо частина емоційних вигуків позбавлена
>   інтонаційних ознак окличності».

Як підсумок, наведу зауваження зі згаданої вище статті О.Мельник:

> Семантика вигука формується залежно від ситуації мовлення та
>   контексту, а певні семантичні варіанти вигука можуть функціонувати в
>   обмеженій кількості комунікативних моделей. Арсенал графічних
>   можливостей передавання вигукових варіантів на письмі досить
>   обмежений, тому складно однозначно з’ясувати, яку саме емоцію чи стан
>   передає конкретний вигук.